# How to recode strings in Stata?

Tags: string, stata, recode

I would like to change the values in my Nationality variable. For some countries, there is a space after the name of the country ("Germany" and "Germany "), so that they don't appear to be the same country when looking at frequencies. I tried using "encode" to make the values numeric, so that I could use "recode" to change the values, but that gave me the error "unknown el Germany in rule". I attached a screenshot.
[Screenshot of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LGaMt.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recode` is for numeric variables only, you can use `replace`.

```
replace Nationality = "Belgium" if Nationality == "Belgium "
```

However, a more convenient way for the problem at hand is `strtrim()`, which removes leading and trailing spaces.

```
replace Nationality = strtrim(Nationality)
```